# Getting the actual on/off value from a radio button instead of 1/0

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to store some data from an [EntityForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) to a txt-file. 
This can be easily done with an entity wrapper, but when I get the value of the radiobutton (boolean) they selected I always get 1 instead of the value attached to that button (male/female).

This is my code:

```
$wrapper=entity_metadata_wrapper('entityform', $submission);
$wrapper->field_sex->value();  //this gives 1 instead of male
```

Comment: Maybe try doing an if statement `if ($wrapper->field_sex->value()) { $wrapper->field_sex->value() = 'male'; } else { $wrapper->field_sex->value() = 'female'; } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to mix up the concept of an input's *value* and its *label*. They're two different things.

The *value* of a boolean field can only be, by definition, 1 or 0. It's a boolean after all. The *label* for the options can be anything.

To load the labels associated with those values, you'll need to load up the field definition:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_sex');
$allowed_values = $info['settings']['allowed_values'];
$label = $allowed_values[$wrapper->field_sex->value()];
```